# MySQL curdate() behavior not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a select query that I'm executing but am coming across an error when using the following logic:

```
and (dre.completion_date >= (curdate() - 1) and dre.completion_date < curdate() );
```

The query above returns zero results in my query, however the following query returns the correct number of results:

```
and (dre.completion_date >= ("2015-01-01" - 1) and dre.completion_date < "2015-01-01" );
```

Why does the hard coded date work but not the function? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the datatype of `completion_date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line that reads:

```
(curdate() - 1)
```

to:

```
(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day)
```

Comment: Yep, that should solve the problem.  the expression `CURDATE() -1` ends up casting the date to a number: today, `select curdate() - 1;` gives me `20150100` - obviously, not what you want :)